# Delete empty rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL database and in one table I have the datetime column **edit_user**. Some rows are blank, and these rows I would like to delete.

I tried

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE edit_user="";
```

but I got the error

> LINE 1: delete from table where edit_user="";

Also, I thought in the column as a blank value could be **0000-00-00**, but there isn't.

How I should execute this command correctly?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE edit_user IS NULL;
```

Comment: can you please give me an explanation for this. why this is working and why = null is not working.

Answer (score 13):

If you are trying to delete empty spaces , try using `=''` instead of `is null`. Hence , if your row contains empty spaces , `is null` will not capture those records. Empty space is not null and null is not empty space.

```
Dec  Hex     Binary    Char-acter Description
0    00  00000000      NUL        null

32  20  00100000      Space       space
```

So I recommend:

```
delete  from foo_table  where bar = ''

#or 

delete  from foo_table  where bar = '' or bar is null 

#or even better , 

delete from foo_table where rtrim(ltrim(isnull(bar,'')))='';
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete rows empty in table

**syntax:**

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

**example:**

Table name: data ---> column name: pkdno

```
DELETE FROM data 
WHERE pkdno IS NULL;
```

**Answer:** 5 rows deleted. (sayso)

Comment: Phil already provided the same answer. You are not adding anything new.

Comment: Sure this is the same answer as Phil, but I like this answer more because it has documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your problem is that you're checking for an empty string using double quotes instead of single quotes. Try just changing to:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE edit_user=''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution, which worked for me:

```sql
DELETE FROM MySchema.MyTable WHERE TheColumn IS NULL OR TRIM(TheColumn) = '';
```