# How can I delete rows with "Empty Strings" in a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, delete-row

I have many rows/records where one of the columns (movieId) is void of any useful values:

[image]

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654614/delete-empty-rows), the following should work:

[image]

...but it doesn't, as you can see in the rectangled "no rows affected"

How can I eliminate/delete all the rows with nothing (but empty space) in the MovieId column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation as to why your `IS NULL` delete is not working is that the `MovieId` values are empty string, rather than `NULL`.  Here is an option you can use to handle both `NULL` and empty string at the same time:

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.ACTORS_MOVIES_M2M
WHERE COALESCE(MovieId, '') = '';
```

Comment: Thanks! Both worked; I'm going to play Robin Hood and give the answer to you but the upcoming Bounty to Clint Eastwood

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I posted first actually.  Don't know if you count that as a criterion towards deciding which answer to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.ACTORS_MOVIES_M2M
WHERE NULLIF(MovieId, '') IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your example above seems to have multiple spaces rather than just a blank value.

You can therefore delete them with something similar to above, but with a trim.

```
FROM dbo.ACTORS_MOVIES_M2M
WHERE LTRIM(MovieId) = '' OR Movie_ID IS NULL;
```

You could also use the COALESCE/NULLIF options above e.g.,

```
FROM dbo.ACTORS_MOVIES_M2M
WHERE COALESCE(LTRIM(MovieId), '') = '';
```